# Matter.js Collision Filtering Not working

Tags: collision, p5.js, matter.js

Inspired by the code bullet I wanted to make a hill climb racing game and so like him, I'm using the p5.js engine but unlike him, I'm going to use matter.js as my physics. Ive finished creating the terrain using perlin noise. And am now creating the car. I don't want to use the matter.js car because there doesn't seem like there is any collision is there so plan b is to create 2 circles that are our wheels that are constraind with each other. Also create a car body that's constraint to the wheel. Now in this I also want it to be so that there is collision between the wheels and the ground and the car body and the ground but not the body and the wheel because I want to use suspension in my car. So my question is how do I make it so that the ground can collide with the car body and wheel but the car body and wheel don't collide with themselves. I've been trying this with many failed attempts with this being the latest https://github.com/KidCoderT/hill-climb-racing and I don't understand why it happens. Ive created 3 different masks.

```
let worldCategory = 0x0002,
carBodyCategory = 0x0003,
carWheelCategory = 0x0004;
```

and applied them separately to each item yet they all collide with each other what am I doing wrong. Please help me thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was just stuck with similar thing, so here's a solution in case anyone is still looking for it:

To filter collisions, beside **categories** you created we also need **masks** which tell Matter engine with which categories will the body collide. So, using your categories:

```
let worldCategory = 0x0002,
carBodyCategory = 0x0003,
carWheelCategory = 0x0004;
```

we need to assign them to the `collisionFilter` property of a matter body, for example:

```
const wheel = Matter.Bodies.circle(xPox, yPos, radius, {
  collisionFilter: {
    category: carWheelCategory
  }
})
const carBody = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(xPox, yPos, width, height, {
  collisionFilter: {
    category: carBodyCategory
  }
})
const ground = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(xPox, yPos, width, height, {
  collisionFilter: {
    category: worldCategory
  }
})
```

Now, we can add masks to each object to tell it with which category it can collide. For example the below will make ground collide with both wheel and carBody:

```
const ground = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(xPox, yPos, width, height, {
  collisionFilter: {
    category: worldCategory,
    mask: wheelCategory | carBodyCategory
  }
})
```

That's how we can precisely control what will collide with what.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
// Assuming that parameters (a, b) contains (a.x, a.y, a.radius) (b.x, b.y, b.radius)

function CircleCollision(a, b) {
  let dst = Math.floor(sqrt((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y)));

  if (dst < a.radius + b.radius) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR:

Use binary numbers with only 1 bit set for your categories

```
const worldCategory = 0b0001;
const carBodyCategory = 0b0010;
const carWheelCategory = 0b0100;
```

Then, when creating the physics objects, set the category, and mask what you want to collide with.

```js
// "this" is a Scene.
const world = this.matter.add.rectangle(10,10,10,10,{
  collisionFilter: {
    mask: carWheelCategory, // will collide with wheel only
    category: worldCategory,
  },
}

const carBody = this.matter.add.rectangle(10,10,10,10,{
  collisionFilter: {
    mask: 0, // will not collide with anything.
    category: carBodyCategory,
  },
}

const carWheel = this.matter.add.circle(10,10,10,{
  collisionFilter: {
    mask: worldCategory, // will collide with world only, and not the car body
    category: carWheelCategory
  },
}
```

##### Combine masks

You can add more masks using the bitwise OR (`|`) operator if you want one object to collide with multiple other objects.

```js
// Let's say we want the world to collide with the carBody AND the carWheel

const world = this.matter.add.rectangle(10,10,10,10,{
  collisionFilter: {
    mask: carWheelCategory | carBodyCategory, // will collide with wheel and body
    category: worldCategory,
  },
}

// It's also important to add the worldCategory on the carBody's mask as well.
const carBody = this.matter.add.rectangle(10,10,10,10,{
  collisionFilter: {
    mask: worldCategory
    category: carBodyCategory,
  },
}
```

### Reason

It's important to understand how MatterJs handles the mask/category filtering. From the documentation, https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_collisionFilter,

> Each body belongs to a collision category, given by collisionFilter.category. This value is used as a bit field and the category should have only one bit set, meaning that the value of this property is a power of two in the range [1, 2^31]. Thus, there are 32 different collision categories available.
>
> Each body also defines a collision bitmask, given by collisionFilter.mask which specifies the categories it collides with (the value is the bitwise AND value of all these categories).
>
> Using the category/mask rules, two bodies A and B collide if each includes the other's category in its mask, i.e. (categoryA & maskB) !== 0 and (categoryB & maskA) !== 0 are both true.

I'd like to put emphasis on **"the category should have only one bit set"**. The filter categories in your question are defined as hexadecimal numbers. This will become a problem when the values are

```js
const worldCategory = 0x0002;
const carBodyCategory = 0x0003;
const carWheelCategory = 0x0004;
```

To understand what I mean, let's take a look at their binary form

```js
const worldCategory = 0b0010;
const carBodyCategory = 0b0011; // <-- We set two bits to `1`, which will cause confusion when setting our masks and categories.
const carWheelCategory = 0b0100;
```

Here's the catch. Every object using the `worldCategory` as their mask will also collide with the carBody. The reason being that MatterJs is using the following rule to filter collisions

> Using the category/mask rules, two bodies A and B collide if each includes the other's category in its mask, i.e. (categoryA & maskB) !== 0 and (categoryB & maskA) !== 0 are both true.

MatterJs uses the bitwise AND (`&`) operator between the mask and the category, and if the result is not `0` (meaning that neither number shares a `1` on the same position in their binary form,) the objects will collide.

Let's write the examples out

```
const worldCategory = 0b0010;
const carBodyCategory = 0b0011;
const carWheelCategory = 0b0100;

function canCollide(mask, category){
  return mask & category !== 0;
}

// returns true, because "0b0010 & 0b0011 = 0b0010", which is 2 in decimal number, and also not equal to 0, thus the objects can collide.
canCollide(worldCategory, carBodyCategory);
```

Disclaimer: I wrote a blog post about the topic with more details, and a live example:

[Understanding Physics Collision filtering with Phaser and MatterJs](https://reitgames.com/news/collision-filtering-phaser)